# Character encoding confusion on Windows

Tags: java, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, windows-1252

I have a simple Java program that takes in hex and converts it to ASCII.
Using Java 8, I compiled the following:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Charset: " + Charset.defaultCharset());
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type a HEX string: ");
        String s = in.nextLine();
        String asciiStr = new String();
        
        //  Split the string into an array
        String[] hexes = s.split(":");
        
        //  For each hex
        for (String hex : hexes) {
            //  Translate the hex to ASCII
            System.out.print(" " + Integer.parseInt(hex, 16) + "|" + (char)Integer.parseInt(hex, 16));
            asciiStr += ((char) Integer.parseInt(hex, 16));
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nthe ASCII string is " + asciiStr);
        
        in.close();
    }
}
```

I am passing in a hex string of `C0:A8:96:FE` to the program. My main concern is the `0x96` value, because it is defined as a control character (characters in the range of 128 - 159).

The output when I run the program without any JVM flags is the following:

```
Charset: windows-1252
Type a HEX string: C0:A8:96:FE
 192|À 168|¨ 150|? 254|þ
the ASCII string is À¨?þ
```

The output when I use the JVM flag `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1` to set the character encoding appears to be the following:

```
Charset: ISO-8859-1
Type a HEX string: C0:A8:96:FE
 192|À 168|¨ 150|– 254|þ
the ASCII string is À¨–þ
```

I'm wondering why, when the character encoding is set to ISO-8859-1, I get the extra Windows-1252 characters for characters 128 - 159? These characters shouldn't be defined in ISO-8859-1, but should be defined in Windows-1252, but it is appearing to be backwards here. In ISO-8859-1, I would think that the `0x96` character is supposed to be encoded as a blank character, but that is not the case. Instead, the Windows-1252 encoding does this, when it should properly encode it as a `–`. Any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

My guess: While the default `Charset` of your JVM may be "windows-1252", your `System.out` is actually using Unicode.

You said:

> when I use the JVM flag -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 to set the character encoding

My experiments below lead me to suspect that whatever you were doing did *not* actually affect the character set used by `System.out`. I believe that in both your runs, when you thought your `System.out` was using "windows-1252" or "ISO-8859-1", your `System.out` was in fact using Unicode, likely UTF-8.

I wish I knew [how to get the `Charset` of `System.out`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66791176/642706).

This behavior might change in the future, with a [proposal (JEP 400) to use UTF-8 by default](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400)  across platforms.

## Details

Actually, you are asking about [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) rather than [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). ASCII has only 128 characters.

You said:

> My main concern is the 0x96 value, because it is defined as a control character (characters in the range of 128 - 159).

Actually, that range of control characters starts at 127 in Unicode (and ASCII), not 128.  Code point 127 is [DELETE character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character). So 127-159 are control characters.

First, let’s split your input string of hex codes.

```java
        final List < String > hexInputs = List.of( "C0:A8:96:FE".split( ":" ) );
        System.out.println( "hexInputs = " + hexInputs );
```

When run.

```
hexInputs = [C0, A8, 96, FE]
```

Now convert each hex text into hex integer. We use that integer as a Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).

Rather than rely on some default character encoding, let's explicitly set the `Charset` of our `System.out`. I'm no expert on this, but some web-searching found the code below where we wrap `System.out` in a new `PrintStream` while setting a `Charset` by its name. I could not find a way to *get* the `Charset` of a `PrintStream`, so [I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66791176/642706).

### UTF-8

```java
        // UTF-8
        System.out.println( "----------|  UTF-8  |--------------------------" );
        try
        {
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream( System.out , true , StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() ); // "UTF-8".

            for ( String hexInput : hexInputs )
            {
                int codePoint = Integer.parseInt( hexInput , 16 );
                String string = Character.toString( codePoint );
                printStream.println( "hexInput: " + hexInput + " = codePoint: " + codePoint + " = string: [" + string + "] = isLetter: " + Character.isLetter( codePoint ) + " = name: " + Character.getName( codePoint ) );
            }
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When run.

```
----------|  UTF-8  |--------------------------
hexInput: C0 = codePoint: 192 = string: [À] = isLetter: true = name: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
hexInput: A8 = codePoint: 168 = string: [¨] = isLetter: false = name: DIAERESIS
hexInput: 96 = codePoint: 150 = string: [] = isLetter: false = name: START OF GUARDED AREA
hexInput: FE = codePoint: 254 = string: [þ] = isLetter: true = name: LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN
```

### Windows-1252

Next, we do the same but for setting [`"windows-1252"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) as the `Charset` of our wrapped `System.out`. Before doing the wrapping, we verify that such a character encoding is actually available on our current JVM.

```java
        // windows-1252
        System.out.println( "----------|  windows-1252  |--------------------------" );

        // Verify windows-1252 charset is available on the current JVM.
        String windows1252CharSetName = "windows-1252";
        boolean isWindows1252CharsetAvailable = Charset.availableCharsets().keySet().contains( windows1252CharSetName );
        if ( isWindows1252CharsetAvailable )
        {
            System.out.println( "isWindows1252CharsetAvailable = " + isWindows1252CharsetAvailable );
        } else
        {
            System.out.println( "FAIL - No charset available for name: " + windows1252CharSetName );
        }

        try
        {
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream( System.out , true , windows1252CharSetName );

            for ( String hexInput : hexInputs )
            {
                int codePoint = Integer.parseInt( hexInput , 16 );
                String string = Character.toString( codePoint );
                printStream.println( "hexInput: " + hexInput + " = codePoint: " + codePoint + " = string: [" + string + "] = isLetter: " + Character.isLetter( codePoint ) + " = name: " + Character.getName( codePoint ) );
            }
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When run.

```
----------|  windows-1252  |--------------------------
isWindows1252CharsetAvailable = true
hexInput: C0 = codePoint: 192 = string: [�] = isLetter: true = name: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
hexInput: A8 = codePoint: 168 = string: [�] = isLetter: false = name: DIAERESIS
hexInput: 96 = codePoint: 150 = string: [?] = isLetter: false = name: START OF GUARDED AREA
hexInput: FE = codePoint: 254 = string: [�] = isLetter: true = name: LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN
```

### Latin-1

And we can try [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) as well, producing yet a different result.

```java
        // ISO-8859-1
        System.out.println( "----------|  Latin-1  |--------------------------" );

        // Verify that  charset is available on the current JVM.
        String latin1CharsetName = "ISO-8859-1"; // Also known as "Latin-1".
        boolean isLatin1CharsetNameAvailable = Charset.availableCharsets().keySet().contains( latin1CharsetName );
        if ( isLatin1CharsetNameAvailable )
        {
            System.out.println( "isLatin1CharsetNameAvailable = " + isLatin1CharsetNameAvailable );
        } else
        {
            System.out.println( "FAIL - No charset available for name: " + latin1CharsetName );
        }

        try
        {
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream( System.out , true , latin1CharsetName );

            for ( String hexInput : hexInputs )
            {
                int codePoint = Integer.parseInt( hexInput , 16 );
                String string = Character.toString( codePoint );
                printStream.println( "hexInput: " + hexInput + " = codePoint: " + codePoint + " = string: [" + string + "] = isLetter: " + Character.isLetter( codePoint ) + " = name: " + Character.getName( codePoint ) );
            }
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When run.

```
----------|  Latin-1  |--------------------------
isLatin1CharsetNameAvailable = true
hexInput: C0 = codePoint: 192 = string: [�] = isLetter: true = name: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH GRAVE
hexInput: A8 = codePoint: 168 = string: [�] = isLetter: false = name: DIAERESIS
hexInput: 96 = codePoint: 150 = string: [�] = isLetter: false = name: START OF GUARDED AREA
hexInput: FE = codePoint: 254 = string: [�] = isLetter: true = name: LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN
```

### Conclusion

So you can see that when hard-coding the `Charset` of our wrapped `System.out`, we do indeed see a difference. With UTF-8, we get actual characters `[À], [¨], [], [þ]` whereas with windows-1252 we get three funky question mark characters and one regular question mark, `[�], [�], [?], [�]`. Remember that we added the square brackets in our code.

This behavior of my code matches my expectations, and apparently meets yours as well. Two of those four hex/decimal integer numbers are letters in Unicode while none of them are letters in [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character set nor in Latin-1. The only mysterious thing to me is that the hex 96 decimal 150 number has two different representations, an empty space with UTF-8 while a question mark with windows-1252, and then a funky-question-mark under Latin-1.

Conclusion: Your `System.out` is not using the `Charset` that you think it is using. I suspect that while the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)’s default `Charset` of your JVM may be named "windows-1252", your `System.out` is actually the Unicode character set, likely with [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding.

---

Note to the reader: If unfamiliar with character sets and character encoding, I recommend the fun and easy-reading post, [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: Your answer is enlightening. I think you're right that the JVM may be using that encoding I specify, but the System.out is using a different one. Very strange behavior. Thank you for the information, I feel more informed about this now. It is interesting to note that the windows-1252 charset substitutes the 150 character for a ? , almost like it doesn't know what the character is supposed to be. I think Windows does that (replacement with a ?) instead of a blank box, for instance.

Comment: Although, in the Windows-1252 character encoding, I believe character 150 is supposed to be an em-dash, not a control character.

Comment: @noc-tune Actually, according to [Wikipedia page on Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), number 150 decimal is *En dash*, while 151 is *Em dash*. I cannot explain why I got `?` rather than an en-dash in my output. So, despite my answering, I really have no idea what is going on! (FYI, In [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) 150 is “undefined”.)