# Get the charset of a PrintStream in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, getter, printstream, charset

I know we can set the [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) of a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html) like this:

```java
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream( System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() );  // "UTF-8".
```

Is there a way to *get* the `Charset` being used by a `PrintStream` object such as [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out)? Something like this:

```
Charset charset = System.out.getCharset() ;
```

…but I cannot find any such getter on `PrintStream`.

This Question was raised while addressing a mystery in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66790488/642706).

Comment: `PrintStream` is documented to have an `OutputStreamWriter` inside it. I guess your last resort is to find that `OutputStreamWriter` field, and call `getEncoding` on it...

Comment: Wouldn't that be the value of system property `file.encoding`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use reflection API like this.

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
Field f = ps.getClass().getDeclaredField("charOut");
f.setAccessible(true);
OutputStreamWriter charOut = (OutputStreamWriter) f.get(ps);
System.out.println(charOut.getEncoding());
```

output:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by stackoverflow.AAA field java.io.PrintStream.charOut
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of stackoverflow.AAA
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

UTF-16
```

You need to pay attention to the last WARNING message.

I found the field `charOut` in my eclipse debugger.

[image]